# Mosaicing video frames into a panorama

Tags: video-editing, panorama

I have some video footage I've shot using a dolly with the camera rotated 90 degrees to the right. Which gives me a sideways tracking shot of a background. Does there exist some kind of software I can create a single image from the video footage? The result I want is one single image of the entire shot.

I guess I could export every Nth frame and use Photoshop (or any other type of panorama software) to merge the images together, but this *would* make it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I know such a program exists...I used it years ago, and it was free, but wasn't all that easy to use. Can't find it on a quick search.

I guess I'd suggest exporting every Nth frame, and using Autopano Pro. You just feed it all the images, and it will spit out a panorama, no manual work needed.